# Remove DELIMITER from phpMyAdmin dump

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, delimiter

I'm making a dump of my MySql database. I'm using `phpMyAdmin` and making dump using Export tab.
The problem is that for `TRIGGERS` `phpMyAdmin` set `DELIMITER //` and then set it to default `DELIMITER ;`, but it generate an `error in SQL syntax` on older versions of phpMyAdmin and in some other cases. Can somebody help me to remove this option in `phpMyAdmin`? Maybe I understand something wrong?

**Sql Code**

```
--
-- Triggers `checklist_question`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `checklist_question_insert`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `checklist_question_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `checklist_question`
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.www_or_app = IF(@APPLICATION IS NULL, 'www', 'app')
//
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `checklist_question_update`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `checklist_question_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `checklist_question`
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.www_or_app = IF(@APPLICATION IS NULL, 'www', 'app')
//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Exception code**

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v1.8.2
Powered by PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.


←[37;41m
       ←[0m
←[37;41m  [Codeception\Exception\Module]
       ←[0m
←[37;41m  (Exception in Db) SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
 that  ←[0m
←[37;41m   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
       ←[0m
←[37;41m  CREATE TRIGGER `checklist_question_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `checkl' at line 1
       ←[0m
←[37;41m  SQL query being executed:
       ←[0m
←[37;41m  DELIMITER //
       ←[0m
←[37;41m  CREATE TRIGGER `checklist_question_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `checklist_question`
       ←[0m
←[37;41m   FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.www_or_app = IF(@APPLICATION IS NULL, 'www', 'app')
       ←[0m
←[37;41m  //
       ←[0m
←[37;41m  DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `checklist_question_update`
       ←[0m
←[37;41m
       ←[0m
```

Comment: can you post the error here..

Answer (score 1):

`DELIMITER` is not a MySQL command. It's a command that your MySQL client needs to support.
Try to replace all `//` with `;` and remove `DELIMITER` declarations.

Comment: I understand this, but this don't solve the problem. I have a number of such triggers, and, as you understnad, I need dump of my database for unit tests. Application grows rapidly, so I need to make such dumps often enough, and it's not very comfortable to delete delimiters from sql code.